# How many leafref is possible inside a leaf in Yang modelling?

Tags: datamodel, ietf-netmod-yang

According to RFC - [RFC 6020 - LeafRef](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#page-124) I can understand that the leaf can contain a leafref which inturn have the path pointing to the instance which is referenced but question is how many leafrefs are possible for one leaf? Only one or many?

Ex.

```
leaf mgmt-interface {
         type leafref {
             path "../interface/name";
         }
         type leafref {
             path "../interface/ip";
         }
     }
```

Is the above possible?

Answer (score 0):

A `leafref` may only target a single `leaf` or `leaf-list` node via `path`. There may only be one `type` substatement to a leaf (also applies to `leaf-list`, `typedef`) and there may only be a single `path` substatement to `type`.

[7.6.2.  The leaf's Substatements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-7.6.2)

```
+--------------+---------+-------------+
| substatement | section | cardinality |
+--------------+---------+-------------+
| config       | 7.19.1  | 0..1        |
| default      | 7.6.4   | 0..1        |
| description  | 7.19.3  | 0..1        |
| if-feature   | 7.18.2  | 0..n        |
| mandatory    | 7.6.5   | 0..1        |
| must         | 7.5.3   | 0..n        |
| reference    | 7.19.4  | 0..1        |
| status       | 7.19.2  | 0..1        |
| type         | 7.6.3   | 1           | <--
| units        | 7.3.3   | 0..1        |
| when         | 7.19.5  | 0..1        |
+--------------+---------+-------------+
```

[12.  YANG ABNF Grammar](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-12)

```
type-stmt           = type-keyword sep identifier-ref-arg-str optsep
                     (";" /
                      "{" stmtsep
                          type-body-stmts
                      "}")

type-body-stmts     = numerical-restrictions /
                     decimal64-specification /
                     string-restrictions /
                     enum-specification /
                     leafref-specification /
                     identityref-specification /
                     instance-identifier-specification /
                     bits-specification /
                     union-specification
                     
leafref-specification =
                     ;; these stmts can appear in any order
                     path-stmt stmtsep
                     [require-instance-stmt stmtsep]

path-stmt           = path-keyword sep path-arg-str stmtend
```

Note: it is not possible to use `union` for `leafref` types in YANG 1.0. This has changed in [YANG 1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-netmod-rfc6020bis-14#section-9.12) however, where any built-in YANG type may appear inside a `union`.

[9.12.  The union Built-In Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-9.12)

> A member type can be of any built-in or derived type, except it MUST
> NOT be one of the built-in types "empty" or "leafref".